# Changing collection name according to query parameters in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, query-string

Can we get data from different collections of same or multiple mongo databases according to the query parameters in nest js ?
For example if parameter says get data from collection A, then collection A data should be displayed if it says get data from collection B, then collection B data should be displayed.

Can we do it in same controller or we need to make multiple controllers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I just have to make two models from different collections and use the desired model according to query parameter by using simple if then else.